# Msg error in console

Tags: command-line, 16.04, zsh

I just changed my zsh theme today to bullet train and I noticed that it prompts the message below upon starting the terminal and after every command execution.

```
prompt_nvm:6: command not found: node
```

a image:

[image]

Comment: Is it when you open the console to use or when you run a certain command in the console?

Comment: when i open, or use commands like: cd, ls

Comment: no, i dont think so, only thing i do is install bullet-train of zsh

Comment: Are you using oh-my-zsh or something? Did you installing anyting related to nodejs?

Comment: yes i using oh-my-zsh, but i didn't install anything about node i use python

Comment: Please edit your question to include important information like zsh, bullet-train, oh-my-zsh, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found in bullet-train's github issues.

> Do you want to see nvm/node segment? If yes - you need to install
>   node. If no - you need to remove it from BULLETTRAIN_PROMPT_ORDER
>   variable. (see
>   https://github.com/caiogondim/bullet-train-oh-my-zsh-theme/wiki/Tips#bullettrain_prompt_order)
>   [origin link](https://github.com/caiogondim/bullet-train-oh-my-zsh-theme/issues/192)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following alias after installing `nodejs` (`apt-get install nodejs`).

`alias node=nodejs`